# Android Studio how to set buttons to the center and give space between two?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

How can I set buttons to the center and give space between two in Android Studio? I want to make a soundboard, so I need this to solve. [Currently state][1]

The currently code:

```
     <RelativeLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/linear"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="TEST1"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                    android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:text="TEST2"
                    android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

            </LinearLayout>


        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true">


        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="TEST1"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:background="@drawable/buttonrectangle"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="TEST2"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"/>

    </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```